# MySQL query to search to match a single word

Tags: php, mysql, search

Here I'm trying to work with a MySQL query which search to match an exact single word.

```
SELECT `text` FROM `tbl_strings` WHERE `text` LIKE "%pencil%"
```

I'd like to get a result with a word "pencil" but not "pencils".
Thanks for all inspirations.

Comment: this will fetch "pencils" also.

Comment: You should use full text search or Try Answer of @Sashi Kant

Comment: A simple `=` operator will suffice if you're only matching a single exact word. You need to explain your question more clearly, since we don't know if you want an exact match or a match from a string.

Comment: Give us some examples

Comment: Try Goutam Pal simply regex query. this one is recommended http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d2ba/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `text` FROM `tbl_strings` WHERE `text` REGEXP '[[:<:]]pencil[[:>:]]'
```

see the SQL fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48924/1

Answer (score 0):

To search for an exact match just do something like:

```
SELECT text FROM tbl_strings WHERE text = 'pencil'
```

Comment: This will only return the string if its only pencil

Comment: You should read the question, then comment and mark people down. I quote: "...match an exact single word."

Answer (score 0):

I have edited  . . Try this

> SELECT `text` FROM `tbl_strings` WHERE `text` LIKE "%pencil" OR `text` LIKE "%pencil %"

Comment: What about `Pencil is Mine`?